# json throwing an invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: php, json

I have one ec2 server with php 5.3 and with 2 virtual hosts: 1 dev and 1 live.

On the dev if someone uploads a file with a bad UTF-8 it ignores the error and it just doesn't convert the variable.

On the live host it throws this error and stops the php script:

> Message: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument.

Any reason I am getting mixed results on the same server?

Comment: I think even in the dev you have this issue but in the dev one error reporting is off for messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Perhaps you do not have error reporting on dev, but you do on live. To test this theory all you need to do is turn [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) off.

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Option 2:

You could try converting the 'file' to UTF-8 automatically using [mb_convert_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

```
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8');
echo json_encode($file);
```

Comment: It was because I have ini_set('display_errors', 1) for dev and ini_set('display_errors', 0) for Live... but this seems backwards.. shouldn't the live ignore the error and dev display it?